# what's the difference between body >:not(element) and :not(body> element)?

Tags: html, css

I think the latter item,

```
:not(body> element)
```

accounts for all the 'element' items that are in the body tag. Is that synomous to

```
body >:not(element)
```

??

Comment: The first selector is incorrect so there is no difference to worry about.

Answer (score 4):

`body >:not(element)` selects all elements that are children of the body except `<element>` elements.

`:not(body> element)` is invalid CSS because [`:not()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) only takes a [simple selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn). If it was valid, it would select everything the other one did but also every element that was not a child of the body (such as the body element itself and any grandchild of the body element).

Answer (score 3):

```
:not(body> element)
```

is invalid since `:not` accepts only [simple selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not), so they re not equal

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that `:not(body> element)` is not valid.

`:not(selector)` only accepts [simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn).

Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation